# How to get index of selected option in Tkinter combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, python-2.x

The following code lets me print out the selected value from the Combobox, but I need to print (get) the index number of selected item in the list. How can I do that?

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

app = Tk()

def OptionCallBack(*args):
    print variable.get()

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")
variable.trace('w', OptionCallBack)

so = ttk.Combobox(app, textvariable=variable)
so.config(values =('Tracing Upstream', 'Tracing Downstream','Find Path'))
so.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='E', padx=10)


app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `current` method on the combobox.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

app = Tk()

def OptionCallBack(*args):
    print variable.get()
    print so.current()

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")
variable.trace('w', OptionCallBack)


so = ttk.Combobox(app, textvariable=variable)
so.config(values =('Tracing Upstream', 'Tracing Downstream','Find Path'))
so.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='E', padx=10)


app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can if you combine [`bind()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) with [`current()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Combobox.html).

Here is a  quick demo:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

app = Tk()

def display_selected_item_index(event): 
   global so
   print 'index of this item is: {}\n'.format(so.current())

def OptionCallBack(*args):
    print variable.get()

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")
variable.trace('w', OptionCallBack)

so = ttk.Combobox(app, textvariable=variable)
so.config(values =('Tracing Upstream', 'Tracing Downstream','Find Path'))
so.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='E', padx=10)    
so.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", display_selected_item_index)  

app.mainloop()
```